# How to skip package structure of class from serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I am using `jackson` to *serialize* and *deserialize*. I am trying to write into redis cache using one package structure class and and I am trying to read with another package structure like below

```
Wirte:- com.ms.Employee
Read:- com.mf.Employee
```

Both classes have same property's only, but while reading from cache it is looking for same package structure class like com.ms.Employee, if not present that class it is throwing some exception. So is there any way to skip fully qualified name of class while serialising and deserializing.

Few people are sugesting `@JsonTypeResolver` `@JsonTypeInfo`, I referred few sites I am not getting exactly why we are using those annotations

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, type="type")
NAME,CLASS,NONE, i tried all Still same
```

Expecting is While Serializing and Deserializing jackson need to skip fully qualified name, just need to consider Class name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Just *describing* what your code is doing is typically not a good start. As said, consider putting together a *minimal* example we can look at.

Comment: If there two classes with same name in two different packages, how json will come to come ?